# Apache2 not asking password on boot

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I have set up a SSL protected site with Apache and PHP.

For each service restart, Apache asks me the SSL key password in order to restart.
My problem is, when I rebooted my server, Apache did not prompt anything about my password, which caused it to stop the start procedure.

```
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
```

"Not finished startup" Apache is already listening port 80 but not running.

Is there any way to enable remove certificate password prompting (on reboot only) or to get prompted for password ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to remove the password partially, either you have a certificate password, or you don't.

You say you're not getting the password prompt, which is possible if it's being started automatically, the password prompt is possibly ending up under the user which starts apache.

I realize it isn't ideal, but I tended to either set apache to not start automatically, or logged on to manually restart. You can put the password in a script, but that's about the same level as not having a password IMHO.

Comment: I finally removed the password for the certificate, you are right, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the doc : https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RemoveSSLCertPassPhrase you have two choices :

- Remove the password from your certificate
- Do a script to give the password to Apache